# how to debug vb.net web app page for a mobile (apple or samsung)

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Normally, I must publish my vb.net ASP.NET web app to the site server, then use an Apple or Samsung device to browse and debug my web page.

Site is down now, and I need to continue development.

Normally, when I debug, I only get the big IE page at " http:// localhost :54802/default.aspx".

How can I get ID to simulate the page browsed on iOS (Apple) or Android (Samsung)?

Comment: Looking at the url.. it looks like you are working on development server, the one which runs when you F5 application from visual studio. If you want it to debug from phone then it is only possible if wifi is available. You can:
1. Configure the application on IIS and make it available on your intranet. 
2. Then access the application on phone by accessing it with ip address where you configured the application or name of the pc. For example : http://198.23.66.10/yourApp.
I have assumed here that both your machine where app is configured and the phone, are on common wifi.

Comment: @kaushalparik27 it looks like he was publishing to a public server.

Comment: Have you considered Electric Mobile? It lets you sort of simulate iPhone browser on your computer. A free trial is [available](http://www.electricplum.com/studio.aspx). Or as Scott Hanselman explains you can use a Lite version [for free](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimulatingAnIPhoneOrIPadBrowserForASPNETMobileWebDevelopmentWithWebMatrix2OrVisualStudio2012.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google offers the product:   Chrome Canary
for mobile device browser animation
[chrome canary](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html)